# Tile server for mapbox

Tags: geoserver

I've tried to get this running with versions 2.14.4 and 2.15.2 without success I can run on version 2.13. I'm trying to figure out the issue, step one is as below;

[image]

In both versions this is what I see after installing the vectortile extension and restarting but this differs from the screengrab shown in the [documentation](https://docs.geoserver.org/maintain/en/user/extensions/vectortiles/install.html). So my question is whether the documentation image is out of date or my install has not worked (2.14.4 with Vectortile extension 2.14.4).

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the bug which means I can confirm that the above screenshot does mean that the vectortiles extension has installed properly